# Xamarin Forms Prism call the method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

How can I call the method async after page appearing?
I tried to do to this by override `OnAppearing()` in ContentPage also this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnAppearing` is an essentially an event handler hiding the sender and EventArgs. If you need to execute this asynchronously you simply need to make it `async`:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    await FooAsync();
}
```

Since you added a tag for Prism I will add that when following the MVVM pattern, you should only be executing code in your code-behind that is View-centric. In other words, this code should be limited to things that change something about the view. Prism 7 does give you the IPageLifecycleAware interface so you can handle `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` inside your ViewModel.